# A call to list all Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types

My theme currently uses this code to call all Categories into a list to pull posts from (in the backend) for a thumbnail widget.

```
$mx_categories_obj = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
$mx_categories = array();
foreach ($mx_categories_obj as $mx_cat) {
$mx_categories[$mx_cat->cat_ID] = $mx_cat->slug;
}
$categories_tmp = array_unshift($mx_categories, "Select a category:");
```

How could I arrange this so that it lists all custom post types instead? I tried using this and it did not work:

```
$cpt_post_types_obj = get_post_types('hide_empty=0');
$cpt_post_types = array();
foreach ($cpt_post_types_obj as $cpt_apt) {
$cpt_post_types[$cpt_apt->apt_ID] = $cpt_apt->slug;
}
$post_types_tmp = array_unshift($cpt_post_types, "Select a category:");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to take a look at the documentation to know how to use a function, you can't just replace them. If you do that you'll see [`get_post_types()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) has to be used different then `get_categories()`. For example you can't use the parameter `hide_empty`. Besides that you have to change the `$output` parameter to `objects`, default is `names`. There are many other possibilities for customizing your output, if you make use of the `$args` and `$operator` parameter. A basic untested example based on what you've tried so far is below.

**Code:**

```
$args = array(
    //  public - Boolean. If true, only public post types will be returned. 
    'public' => true,
    // _builtin - Boolean. 
    // If true, will return WordPress default post types.
    // Use false to return only custom post types. 
    '_builtin' => false
);
$output = 'objects';
$operator = 'and';
$cpt_post_types_obj = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
$cpt_post_types = array();
foreach ( $cpt_post_types_obj as $cpt_apt ) {
    $cpt_post_types[] = $cpt_apt->name;
}
$post_types_tmp = array_unshift($cpt_post_types, "Select a post type:");
```

---

**Update:**

As the constructing of the custom post type array works with above code, the problem might have to do with your dropdown. Below an example how you can do it.

**Code:**

```
echo '<select name="post_type_dropdown">';
    foreach ( $cpt_post_types_obj as $cpt_apt ) {
        echo '<option value="'. $cpt_apt->name .'">'. $cpt_apt->name . '</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
```

---

**2nd Update:**

Like I said, it's working for me. Use below code, just put it into your `functions.php` to test, debug it.

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse132165_pt_list_debug' );
function wpse132165_pt_list_debug() {
    $args = array(
        //  public - Boolean. If true, only public post types will be returned. 
        'public' => true,
        // _builtin - Boolean. 
        // If true, will return WordPress default post types.
        // Use false to return only custom post types. 
        '_builtin' => false
    );
    $output = 'objects';
    $operator = 'and';
    $cpt_post_types_obj = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
    // open up the next line like this /** to comment the code until the next /**/
    /**/
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($cpt_post_types_obj);
    echo '</pre>';
    /**/
    $cpt_post_types = array();
    foreach ($cpt_post_types_obj as $cpt_apt) {
        $cpt_post_types[] = $cpt_apt->name;
    }
    /**/
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($cpt_post_types);
    echo '</pre>';
    /**/
    echo '<select name="post_type_dropdown">';
        foreach ( $cpt_post_types_obj as $cpt_apt ) {
            echo '<option value="'. $cpt_apt->name .'">'. $cpt_apt->labels->name . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: Strange, absolutely no errors for me, the code works just fine. There is [get_post_type_archive_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link) and [get_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type). @user46040

Comment: Take a look at `$wp_post_types` to see all you available ones, like this: `global $wp_post_types; echo '<pre>'; print_r($wp_post_types); echo '</pre>';`. It sounds a bit like you're actually not having the custom post types, but you said they are available and correctly used, **but** if so my code ansolutely should work, so I don't know how to help you further. @user46040

Comment: Thank you again. I'll do some more research. Your patience was most appreciated.